# More efficient SQL than using "A UNION (B in A)"?

Tags: sql, union, where-clause

**Edit 1 (clarification):** Thank you for the answers so far! The response is gratifying.
I want to clarify the question a little because based on the answers I think I did not describe one aspect of the problem correctly (and I'm sure that's my fault as I was having a difficult time defining it even for myself).
Here's the rub: The result set should contain ONLY the records with tstamp BETWEEN '2010-01-03' AND '2010-01-09', AND the *one* record where the tstamp IS NULL for each order_num in the first set (there will *always* be one with null tstamp for each order_num).
The answers given so far appear to include *all* records for a certain order_num if there are *any* with tstamp BETWEEN '2010-01-03' AND '2010-01-09'. For example, if there were another record with order_num = 2 and tstamp = 2010-01-12 00:00:00 it should *not* be included in the result.

**Original question:**
Consider an orders table containing id (unique), order_num, tstamp (a timestamp), and item_id (the single item included in an order). tstamp is null, unless the order has been modified, in which case there is another record with identical order_num and tstamp then contains the timestamp of when the change occurred.

Example...

```
id  order_num  tstamp               item_id
__  _________  ___________________  _______
 0          1                           100
 1          2                           101
 2          2  2010-01-05 12:34:56      102
 3          3                           113
 4          4                           124
 5          5                           135
 6          5  2010-01-07 01:23:45      136
 7          5  2010-01-07 02:46:00      137
 8          6                           100
 9          6  2010-01-13 08:33:55      105
```

What is the most efficient SQL statement to retrieve all of the orders (based on order_num) which have been modified one or more times during a certain date range? In other words, for each order we need all of the records with the same order_num (including the one with NULL tstamp), for each order_num WHERE at least one of the order_num's has tstamp NOT NULL AND tstamp BETWEEN '2010-01-03' AND '2010-01-09'. It's the "WHERE at least one of the order_num's has tstamp NOT NULL" that I'm having difficulty with.

The result set should look like this:

```
id  order_num  tstamp               item_id
__  _________  ___________________  _______
 1          2                           101
 2          2  2010-01-05 12:34:56      102
 5          5                           135
 6          5  2010-01-07 01:23:45      136
 7          5  2010-01-07 02:46:00      137
```

The SQL that I came up with is this, which is essentially "A UNION (B in A)", but it executes slowly and I hope there is a more efficient solution:

```
SELECT history_orders.order_id, history_orders.tstamp, history_orders.item_id
FROM
   (SELECT orders.order_id, orders.tstamp, orders.item_id
    FROM orders
    WHERE orders.tstamp BETWEEN '2010-01-03' AND '2010-01-09')
    AS history_orders
UNION
SELECT current_orders.order_id, current_orders.tstamp, current_orders.item_id
FROM
   (SELECT orders.order_id, orders.tstamp, orders.item_id
    FROM orders
    WHERE orders.tstamp IS NULL)
    AS current_orders
WHERE current_orders.order_id IN
   (SELECT orders.order_id
    FROM orders
    WHERE orders.tstamp BETWEEN '2010-01-03' AND '2010-01-09');
```

Comment: I'm curious about performance of the provided queries, maybe you could share test results?

Comment: I will report on the performance improvement of the final solution shortly - it is significant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you again for all the suggestions. I found three solutions that work, including my original. At the end I've added some performance results, which are not as great as I had hoped. If anyone can improve on this I would be thrilled!

1) The best solution found so far seems to be:

```
SELECT history_orders.order_id, history_orders.tstamp, history_orders.item_id
FROM
   (SELECT orders.order_id, orders.tstamp, orders.item_id
    FROM orders
    WHERE orders.tstamp BETWEEN '2010-01-03' AND '2010-01-09'
    OR orders.tstamp IS NULL)
    AS history_orders
WHERE history_orders.order_id IN
   (SELECT orders.order_id
    FROM orders
    WHERE orders.tstamp BETWEEN '2010-01-03' AND '2010-01-09');
```

2) I also tried using EXISTS in place of IN, which requires an additional WHERE clause in the last SELECT:

```
SELECT history_orders.order_id, history_orders.tstamp, history_orders.item_id
FROM
   (SELECT orders.order_id, orders.tstamp, orders.item_id
    FROM orders
    WHERE orders.tstamp BETWEEN '2010-01-03' AND '2010-01-09'
    OR orders.tstamp IS NULL)
    AS history_orders
WHERE EXISTS
   (SELECT orders.order_id
    FROM orders
    WHERE history_orders.order_id = orders.order_id
    AND orders.tstamp BETWEEN '2010-01-03' AND '2010-01-09');
```

3) And finally there is my original solution, using UNION.

Comments:
To comment on the table size, my actual "real world" problem involves 4 tables (connected with inner joins) containing 98, 2189, 43897, 785656 records respectively.

Performance - I ran each solution three times and here are my real world results:
1: 52, 51, 51 seconds
2: 54, 54, 53 s
3: 56, 56, 56 s

Comment: Do you have indexes on order_id and tstamp?

Comment: No, and I don't have the power to modify the design as this is not a key report. It will not be run very often so I'm fairly satisfied with what I have now. Not that I'm not interested in ways to improve things further, just for my own knowledge!

Answer (score 3):

perhaps a subquery:

```
select * from order o where o.order_num in (select distinct
  order_num from order where tstamp between '2010-01-03' and '2010-01-09')
```

Comment: +1 for being the most readable of the first three near-identical solutions.

Comment: So, after including the change necessary based on my clarification ("Edit 1") in my original question, my solution is to use this answer while adding subquery to the first select with a WHERE clause that limits the results to
tstamp BETWEEN '2010-01-03' AND '2010-01-09'
OR tstamp IS NULL.
I will add a complete and correct answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've misunderstood, something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT o1.id, o1.order_num, o.tstamp, o.item_id
FROM  orders o1
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM orders o2 
    WHERE o1.order_num = o2.order_num 
        AND o2.tstamp BETWEEN '2010-01-03' AND '2010-01-09')
```

Benefit of using EXISTS is that it stops as soon as it fines the first match.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's very late for repliying but I just saw this posting and I thought maybe I should try this once, how about this query, it's really very small as compared to all of the above solutions and solves the purpose.

```
select * from orders_gc where order_num in 
    (select order_num
     from orders_gc 
     group by order_num 
     having count(id) > 1 and 
     MAX(tstamp) between '03-jan-2010' and '09-jan-2010')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I got your question right. This should return all orders which have on order that has been changed within the provided timestamp.

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.tstamp, o.item_id
FROM orders o
JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT o2.order_num
       FROM orders o2
       WHERE o2.tstamp BETWEEN '2010-01-03' AND '2010-01-09' ) o3
ON ( o3.order_num = o.order_num )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can self-join the table. Simplified, this would look like:

```
select order_id
from orders all_orders
inner join orders not_null_orders
    on all_orders.order_id = not_null_orders.order_id
where
    not_null_orders.tstamp is not null
    and all_orders.tstamp between '2010-01-03' AND '2010-01-09'
```